# SPD 2010 workflow get cancelled/failed

Tags: 2010

I have a created SPD workflow contains Start Approval Process. In the general setting  I have checked "only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks".  This workflow was associated to a Form Library contain infopath form.  WF will trigger automatically upon form submission.  The users are given with a customized permission level "Contribute_NoDELETE" (basically Contribute permission by exclusion of Delete permission).   This WF was working fine with no issues.  Recently we noticed the workflows get cancelled by System account and sometime it shows "error occured" etc..   We tried to resolve this issue including re creation of entire workflow. But no luck.

But I found workflow working fine as when I unchecked "only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks" option !.

I need to select "only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks".  if I select this option WF is failing.  How to resolve this ? Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what goes wrong with your specific workflow, but I think a possible solution could be to do this:

1. create an impersonation step and within this step:
2. use action "Replace list item permission"
3. Give relevant permissions to the people that should be able to see/edit the current item

It is very important that the first user you add to the "replace permission action" is the user that executes the wf (normally the wf author). You must give full controll to this user. Otherwise the wf will fail immediately, since the user executing the wf just lost write access to the element the wf is executed upon.

People who have no read permission will not see the relevant item in the list after the permissions have been set.

It seems to me, that the problem you are encountering is that the user executing the wf loses write permissions for the element in question.